# Can't send e-mail using AWS SES: didn't I configure it properly?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, email, aws-sdk, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send e-mails from a NodeJS application running on an EC2 machine, but I'm getting an **access denied error** that I wasn't expecting. I followed this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) and now my scenario is (real domains, addresses and IDs were changed):

- The `example.com` domain is verified and configured in the `us-east-1` region to send e-mail in AWS SES. Still in sandbox mode, in case it matters
- The `my@email.com` address is verified, so I can send e-mails to it. I can send an e-mail from `noreply@example.com` to `my@email.com` using the AWS Console.
- The `MyEC2MachineRole` has the following policy attached to it, so that it can send e-mails only using `example.com` domain. This policy is similar to an [example in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sending-authorization-policy-examples.html#sending-authorization-policy-example-action) (except for the missing `Principal`):

  ```
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
          "ses:SendEmail",
          "ses:SendRawEmail"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:111111111111:identity/example.com"
      }
    ]
  }
  ```

When I try to run the following code, based on the [SDK documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/ses-examples-sending-email.html):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

async function main() {
  try {
    const client = new AWS.SES({ apiVersion: '2010-12-01' });
    const result = await client.sendEmail({
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: ['my@email.com']
      },
      Message: {
        Body: {
          Text: {
            Charset: 'UTF-8',
            Data: 'Test',
          },
        },
        Subject: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: 'Test e-mail',
        },
      },
      Source: 'noreply@example.com'
    }).promise();
    console.log('Sent', result);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error', err);
  }
}
main();
```

I get the following error:

> User `arn:aws:sts::111111111111:assumed-role/MyEC2MachineRole/i-0123456789abcdefg` is not authorized to perform `ses:SendEmail` on resource `arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:111111111111:identity/my@email.com`

If I change the destination address to any other e-mail under `example.com` domain it works. Also it works if I change the `Resource` on the policy to `*`.

Isn't `Resource` the address/domain that is sending the e-mail? Why is it trying to operate on an resource related to the destination address? Does it relate to this AWS SES configuration being still in sandbox mode?

Answer (score 3):

Now that the account isn't in the sandbox, the error stopped to happen. While in sandbox, it might need extra permissions to send e-mail, such as permissions to operate on the destination resource.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using credentials associated with an IAM user? If this is the case, you need to assign a policy(`AmazonSESFullAccess`) to the IAM user that will allow those specific actions in SES.

Comment: No, the app was using credentials defined by a role attached to the EC2 instance it was running onto.